# How To add user name and profile picture to Superfish menu

Tags: users, navigation

I am using [Superfish](https://www.drupal.org/project/superfish) module to obtain drop down menus. I would like to have one *parent* menu link as a *username* and *user image*, then *child* menu links will be under it when hovered over.

Example of this is [airbnb.com](https://www.airbnb.com/) when logged in.

I do not know much PHP and do most of my work with CSS and already created modules.

Comment: check this link http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10301/user-picture-and-name-in-user-menu

Comment: I saw that post, curios if there is a module solution rather than code. Also curious if Superfish gets in the way for any reason?

Answer (score 1):

I found a somewhat unnecessarily complex, but working, answer.

1. Install [Menu Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_views) module.
2. Create a View User List Block and add a relationship *User:Profile*.
3. Add a contextual filter *user:uid* and set *Provide default value* as *User ID from logged in user*.
4. Add 2 fields, *User: Picture* and *User: Name*
5. Change Access to *Role* and choose all roles that should see this View.
6. Add CSS classes and style

Note: At this time a issue exists with [Menu Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_views) and requires a fix found [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2557327).